# Optimize string.Replace method

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of 200+ words that are not allowed on a website. The `string.Replace` method below takes ~80ms. If I increase `s < 1000` by a factor of 10.00 to `s < 10,000` this delay goes to ~834ms, a 10.43 increase. I am woried about the scalability of this function, especially if the list increases in size. I was told strings are immutable and `text.Replace()` is creating 200 new strings in memory. Is there something similar to a `Stringbuilder` for this?

```
List<string> FilteredWords = new List<string>();
FilteredWords.Add("RED");
FilteredWords.Add("GREEN");
FilteredWords.Add("BLACK");
for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
{ FilteredWords.Add("STRING " + i.ToString()); }

string text = "";

//simulate a large dynamically generated html page
for (int s = 1; s < 1000; s++)
{ text += @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim BLACK cetero cu nam.
            No vix platonem sententiae, pro wisi congue graecis id, GREEN assum interesset in vix.
            Eum tamquam RED pertinacia ex."; }

// This is the function I seek to optimize
foreach (string s in FilteredWords)
{ text = text.Replace(s, "[REMOVED]"); }
```

Comment: Why are these words not allowed?  There are many ways of representing  words that may be blocked without being filtered.

Comment: Colors are placeholders, obviously. Key terms, profanity, html tags, scripts, etc. need to be visibly scrubbed. We have a list. Please elaborate on "blocked without being filtered".

Comment: I would try to use regular expression. It is also getting slower when you have long expressions but it is worth a try. The other option would be to write your own Replace method - go throught the whole string a try to lookup each word in your blocked words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder.Replace` and try to do it as a batch operation.  That is to say you should try to only create the `StringBuilder` once as it has some overhead.  It won't necessarily be a lot faster but it will be much more memory efficient.

You should also probably only do this sanitation once instead of every time data is requested.  If you're reading the data from the database you should consider sanitizing it once when the data is inserted into the database, so there is less work to do when reading and displaying it to the page.

Comment: Thank you for your input. _you should consider sanitizing it once when the data is inserted into the database_ - I would like to be able to see what the filtered words are on my end, otherwise, very good suggestion.

Comment: @Zerkey - "I would like to be able to see what the filtered words are on my end" - then store both sanitized and unsanitized, if they are different.  If they're the same, which I guess they probably will be most of the time, then only store once to save space.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect most of the text to be relatively nice than scanning whole text first for matching words could be better approach. You can also normalize words text at the same time to catch some standard replacements.

I.e. scan string by matching individual words (i.e. Regular expression like `"\w+"`), than for each detected word lookup (potentially normalized value) in dictionary of words to replace.

You can either simply scan first to get list of "words to replace" and than just replace individual word later, or scan and build resulting string at the same time (using `StringBuilder` or `StreamWriter`, obviously not `String.Concat` / `+`).

Note: Unicode provides large number of good characters to use, so don't expect your effort to be very successful. I.e. try to find "cool" in following text: "you are сооl".

Sample code (relying on [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for tokenization and building the string and `HashSet` for matches).

```
var toFind = FilteredWords.Aggregate(
      new HashSet<string>(), (c, i) => { c.Add(i); return c;});

text = new Regex(@"\w+")
   .Replace(text, m => toFind.Contains(m.Value) ? "[REMOVED]" : m.Value));
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this. It was a horrible idea. `s < 1000` took 2,031ms to complete and `s < 10,000` took almost two full minutes to complete. It is much more efficient to check a string for the presence of a word than it is to check each `"\w+` match against a list/dictionary/hash.

Comment: @Zerkey - I've added sample of code that I meant... It shows 4x improvement over your code. I'm not sure why your version is so much slower (hard to reason without code).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but this is how I would go about solving the problem.

You will need to create a tree structure that contains your dictionary of words to be replaced. The class may be something like:

```
public class Node 
{
    public Dictionary<char, Node> Children;
    public bool IsWord;
}
```

Using a dictionary for the Children may not be the best choice, but it provides the easiest example here. Also, you will need a constructor to initialize the `Children` field. The `IsWord` field is used to deal with the possibility that a redacted "word" may be the prefix of another redacted "word". For example, if you want to remove both "red" and "redress".

You will build the tree from each character in each of the replacement words. For example:

```
public void AddWord ( string word ) 
{
    // NOTE: this assumes word is non-null and contains at least one character...

    Node currentNode = Root;

    for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < word.Length; iIndex++)
    {
        if (currentNode.Children.ContainsKey(word[iIndex])))
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.Children[word[iIndex];
            continue;
        }

        Node newNode = new Node();
        currentNode.Children.Add(word[iIndex], newNode);
        currentNode = newNode;
    }

    // finished, mark the last node as being a complete word..
    currentNode.IsWord = true;
}
```

You'll need to deal with case sensitivity somewhere in there. Also, you only need to build the tree once, afterwards you can use it from any number of threads without worrying about locking because you will be only reading from it. (Basically, I'm saying: store it in a static somewhere.)

Now, when you are ready to remove words from your string you will need to do the following:

- Create a StringBuilder instance to store the result
- Parse through your source string, looking for the start and stop of a "word". How you define "word" will matter. For simplicity I would suggest starting with `Char.IsWhitespace` as defining word separators.
- Once you have determined that a range of character is a "word", starting from the root of the tree, locate the child node associated with the first character in "word".
- If you do not find a child node, the entire word is added to the `StringBuilder`
- If you find a child node, you continue with the next character matching against Children of the current node, until you either run out of characters or out of nodes.
- If you reach the end of the "word", check the last node's `IsWord` field. If `true` the word is excluded, do not add it to the `StringBuilder`. If `IsWord` is `false`, the word is not replaced and you add it to the `StringBuilder`
- Repeat until you have exhausted the input string.

You will also need to add word separators to the `StringBuilder`, hopefully that will be obvious as you parse the input string. If you are careful to only use the start and stop indices within the input string, you should be able to parse the entire string without creating any garbage strings.

When all of this is done, use `StringBuilder.ToString()` to get your final result.

You may also need to consider Unicode surrogate codepoints, but you can *probably* get away without worrying about it.

Beware, I typed this code here directly, so syntax errors, typos and other accidental misdirections are probably included.

Comment: Why build a custom data structure? A basic HashSet would likely be significantly faster and have much lower memory usage. If there were many similar words then a radix tree might make sense, but with only a few hundred I doubt it.

Comment: Sure, a `HashSet` could be used to store the word list. The OP seems worried about the creation of garbage strings though. Each "word" would have to be allocated into a new string to be used as a key in the `HashSet`, which would result in more garbage creation.

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth answer.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted that concern - he's talking about garbage strings during replacement which as you correctly point out a StringBuilder will solve. But creating a custom tree as the word lookup will use far more memory than a single HashSet instance that is reused, and be far slower, while adding significant unneeded complexity.

Comment: The OP's problem is quadratic complexity and this search tree solves that. +1 A HashSet cannot solve it because it can only match full words, not substrings.

Answer (score 0):

The real regular expression solution would be:

```
var filteredWord = new Regex(@"\b(?:" + string.Join("|", FilteredWords.Select(Regex.Escape)) + @")\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
text = filteredWord.Replace(text, "[REMOVED]");
```

I don’t know whether this is faster (but note that it also only replaces whole words).